If $a_n\in(0,1)$, the sum $\sum_{n=1}^t a_n \prod_{m=n+1}^t (1-a_m)$ converges to $1$?
To prove that there exists a sequence $\{a_n\}_n$ with $a_n \in (0,1)$, such that
$$\sum_{n=1}^t a_n \prod_{m=n+1}^t (1-a_m)$$
converges is easy. Because since everything is positive and the products are all less than $1$, we have
$$\sum_{n=1}^t a_n \prod_{m=n+1}^t (1-a_m) \leq \sum_{n=1}^t a_n.$$
And if we choose $a_n = \frac{1}{2^n}$, then
$$ \lim_{t\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^t a_n \prod_{m=n+1}^t (1-a_m) \leq \lim_{t\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^t a_n = 1.$$
However, I am wondering if the series converge for any $a_n\in(0,1)$, and more importantly, what are the conditions in $a_n$ for which
$$ \lim_{t\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^t a_n \prod_{m=n+1}^t (1-a_m) = 1?
$$
We can assume that for $t=1$, in the first summand of the series, the product is $1$, i.e. there is on product.
My intuition tells me that this must converge for any $\{a_n\}_n$ since the product can make the summands decay too fast even if $a_n$ are big. But I have no clue when this converges precisely to $1$ or not.
If anyone could provide any tip that would be pretty much welcome.
Thank you

Can you prove, such as using induction, that the sum is equal to $$1-\prod_{m=1}^{t}(1-a_m)\quad?$$

And then see here for when the product in Sangchul's comment converges.

@SangchulLee, yes! Thank you for that tip. Now this converges whenever the product converges, and converges to 1 whenever the product goes to 0!

@AdamRubinson, thank you for your comment. Based on this, to see when the product converges to 0, I must have that the series $\sum_n^\infty(-a_n)$ diverges to $-\infty$, right?

@AlescRun Run Yes, I believe that is correct.
